Gauge invariance issues of YM theories in 2D Euclidean space
In order to be clear, I will write down every component explicitly. Also, I assume Euclidean metric in this post, so that spacetime indices are written as $i,j$ rather than $\mu, \nu$.
Following Wiki, the curvature or field strength tensor for a YM theory is given by
\begin{equation}
F^a_{ij}:=\partial_i A^a_j - \partial_j A^a_i +f^{abc}A^b_i A^c_j
\end{equation}
where $A^a_j$ is the gauge field and $a,b,c$ are Lie-algebra indices and $f^{abc}$ is the structure constant.
Then, it is well known that unless $f^{abc}=0$ (Abelian), this $F^a_{ij}$ is NOT gauge-invariant in general:
\begin{equation}
\delta F^a_{ij}= \epsilon^{b}f^{abc}F^c_{ij}
\end{equation}
where $\delta$ is an infinitesimal gauge transform. This formula is from Eq. (15.1.14) of Weinberg QFT textbook volume 2.
Rather, it is $F^2:=F^a_{ij} F^a_{ij}$ which remains invariant under local gauge action.
Until now, I have dealt with general Euclidean space with arbitrary dimensions. Now, I restrict to $2D$, so that $i,j \in \{1,2\}$.
In this case, the complete axial gauge seems identifiable with gauge-invariant quantities. For example, look at Eq. (2.4) and (2.5) in p.579 of the paper by Bruce Driver:

$\mu(dA):=Z^{-1}\exp\Bigl[\frac{-1}{2g_0^2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \partial_2 A_1(x) \partial_2 A_1(x)dx \Bigr] DA$ is the functional measure with complete axial gauge.


$\mu(dF):=Z^{-1}\exp\Bigl[\frac{-1}{2g_0^2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}F(x)F(x)dx \Bigr] DF$ is the functional measure in manifestly gauge-invariant form.

It is shown there (at least heuristically) that these two measures are related to each other just by "linear" change of variables.
Now, my main question is as follows:

Definition 2.5 in the same page of the same paper deals only with the field strength tensor $F$ itself, NOT its gauge-invariant square $F^2$ defined above. In lieu with above $\mu(dA)$ and $\mu(dF)$, does it imply that $F$ itself is already gauge-invariant in $2D$?

$2D$ seems to simplify many thinigs to the point of blurring distinctions between gauge fixing and gauge invariance...Could anyone please clarify for me?

You’ve dropped the subscript $\rho$ from the formula, which denotes the Killing form. (2.5) has two copies of $F$, as you show, so, combined with the Killing for, it is the square, just as in Weinberg’s formula. (Technically, it’s the Killing form up to a constant.)

@AaronBergman Oops...thank you for pointing out. Hopefully it does not affect the main contents of the question..

The answer to the question is that the $F$ is not invariant, but the trace in (2.1) makes everything gauge invariant.

@AaronBergman Yes I understand and agree. But my point was more on identifying (2.4) and (2.5) so easily just by linear transform, which seems like a feature of $2D$ and gave me the false hope that $F$ itself might be somehow gauge-invariant.

Focusing on your question itself, regardless of the specific paper you're referring to, $F$ is of course not gauge-invariant in the non-Abelian case, even in 2 (Euclidean) space-time dimensions. It transforms homogeneously, $F \rightarrow F' = UFU^{\dagger } $, under a gauge transformation $U$. I.e., $F$ can be rotated in internal (color) space, locally in space-time.

Ok. Then, I would guess the paper only considered $F$ (in axial gauge) rather than $F^2$ because gauge-invariant partition function can be identified with one in axial gauge...

Once you've completely fixed a gauge, you have identified a unique representativeon each gauge orbit and can use it as a bona fide dynamical variable, be it $A$ or $F$ or anything else you can unambiguously map your variables into.

Yes, I agree. However,  they cannot be "identified" with gauge-invariant quantities (including physical observables) in general. I think that such identification is possible only in $2D$, as shown in above two functional measures in my question.

I'm a bit leery of this "complete axial gauge" which, from your description, seems to be $A_2 =0$. In general, the gauge transformation required to achieve this is infrared singular, and therefore this is not a viable gauge condition. You can only achieve $\partial_2 A_2 =0$. There seems to be no vestige of this additional degree of freedom in your description.

The terminology appears verbatim in the quoted paper. And sorry that I did not write sufficient details of the paper in my question to make this gauge fixing explicit..

I guess that $2D$ resolves such IR issues as well..

No, 2D doesn't resolve the infrared issues. On the contrary, decreasing dimensionality reduces ultraviolet issues, but conversely exacerbates infrared issues.

$A$ in the paper is a Lie-algebra-valued tempered distribution, and gauge fixing seems to be in the sense of distributions too. In that case, there seems no problem.

The tempered distributions may help with ultraviolet issues, but I'm skeptical that they help, or are even compatible with the infrared problems. The Polyakov loop in the (compactified) 2-direction is gauge-invariant, and trying to force $A_2 $ to be zero then implies a nontrivial contribution at infinity in order to keep the Polyakov loop unchanged.

Test functions are Schwartz class, which means that they decay to $0$ at infinity faster than any polynomial. So, I guess IR issues may be resolved this way. The quoted paper does not seem to address them explicitly, but I don't think it is entirely wrong..
